# append() triggers on('click')

Tags: jquery

I am trying to prevent an on click event from firing and I have done just about everything I can think of. What is happening is you click on a submit button which then does a bit of validation and if fails I present a tooltip for the reason. To show the tool tip I enter `$element.append($tooltip)` which then triggers `$(body).on('click', function() {})`

I have verified that if I remove the append the click is not triggered.

Does anyone know why an append it triggering the click event?

Here is more code. This is the actual ToolTip code:

```
//Sets up a tooltip to display feedback
//position: top, bottom or right
NG.Tooltip = function (target, message, timeout, position, doAdjust) {
    var tt = (this == NG ? {} : this); //Prevent people from accidentally missing the "new" keyword and corrupting the global NG object
    var $target = $(target);
    var $targetParent = $target.parent();
    var $offsetParent = $target.offsetParent();
    tt.targetElement = $target.get(0);
    if(!tt.targetElement){
        return;
    }

    //Remove previous tooltip if there is one already attached to target element
    if (tt.targetElement.ngTooltip)
        tt.targetElement.ngTooltip.Remove();

    if (!timeout) timeout = 2000;

    var $div = tt.div = $('<div class="ngTooltip">' + message + '</div>');
    var pos = $target.position();
    var posParent = $targetParent.position();
    if (position == 'bottom') {
        $div.css({ "left": (pos.left) + "px", "top": (pos.top + $target.outerHeight() + 10) + "px" });
    }
    else if (position == 'top') {
        $div.css({ "left": (pos.left) + "px", "top": (pos.top) + "px" });
    }
    else if (position == 'parent-bottom-left') {
        $div.css({ "left": (posParent.left) + "px", "top": (pos.top + $target.outerHeight() + 10) + "px" });
    }
    else {
        $div.css({ "left": (pos.left + $target.outerWidth() + 10) + "px", "top": pos.top + "px" });
    }

    // commenting out this allows the code to go without triggering the click
    //$offsetParent.append($div);

    if (position == 'parent-bottom-left') {
        if ((posParent.left + $div.width()) > $offsetParent.width()) {
            $div.css("width", ($offsetParent.width() - (posParent.left + 15)) + "px");
        }
    }

    //Default to adjust it onscreen.
    //But there are certain cases such as popping up the url of a (link) on hover where adjusting it would not work out well
    if (doAdjust == null || doAdjust == true) {
        NG.AdjustPopupOnScreen($div);
    }

    tt.Remove = function (elem) {
        if (tt.timeoutId)
            window.clearTimeout(tt.timeoutId);
        $div.unbind('click'); //removes click event attached
        $div.remove();
        tt.targetElement.ngTooltip = null;
    };

    $div.click(tt.Remove);
    tt.timeoutId = null;
    if (timeout > 0)
        tt.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () { tt.Remove(); }, timeout);

    tt.targetElement.ngTooltip = this;
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Please post some more of your code.

Comment: The only way this could be happening is if $tooltip has javascript inside of it that triggers the click event.

Comment: @KevinB I looked all over the place for any possibility of the new element containing a trigger but none exist. I am literally just appending a div to another div.

Comment: Just for completeness, what are you passing in as "message"?

Comment: message is a string: Cannot send a blank entry.

Comment: "Hello World" for example? or is it auto generated from somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have seen this in my code. I ended up examining the $(body).on(click) to determine the event type `event.type` and it returned "DOMNodeInserted". Simple search and I found `.on('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {` which had `$('body').trigger('click');`

Thank you everyone for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, when I want Javascript to stop firing, I use `event.stopPropagation`:

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried to lay in the e.stopPropagation() all over the place trying to prevent it but it seems the only code that prevents the click is removing the one line I talked about.